# Amazon SES: How to speed-up curl for this PHP example?

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services

My Amazon Simple Email Service account can theoretically process 14 emails/second but my code is only achieving 1 or 2 per second. Any help on how to increase the rate of HTTP-POSTs is appreciated. I'm pasting my code below to solicit ideas. If possible, post your code ideas rather than links. Thanks!

NOTE: The code below is contained in a **foreach** loop that references a database of emails. Each email I'm sending via HTTP-POST is personalized as seen in the $MAIL string and sent to via the curl code block below. I should also mention that I do not care about the HTTP-POST response.

```
$DATE = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s e');
$HASH = hash_hmac('sha1', $DATE, $AWSPRI, true);
$KEYS = base64_encode($HASH);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Host: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Date: ".$DATE;
  $auth = "AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=".$AWSPUB;
  $auth .= ",Algorithm=HmacSHA1,Signature=".$KEYS;
$headers[] = "X-Amzn-Authorization: ".$auth;
$url = "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/";
$MAIL =  "Action=SendEmail&Source=".$FROM_ENCODE."&ReturnPath=".$BOUNCE_ENCODE."&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=".$SUBSCRIBER_ENCODE."&Message.Subject.Data=".$SUBJECT_ENCODE."&Message.Body.Html.Data=".$EMAIL_BODY_ENCODE;
$aws = curl_init();
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $MAIL);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($aws, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($aws);
curl_close($aws);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could put some benchmarking code in to find out the bottlenecks.

Secondly, a shot in the dark, you could reuse http connections.

Thirdly, and probably the right answer, get a beefed up dedicated server sitting in a high bandwidth thru-put international network center - James Bond style.

Comment: 1) The bottleneck is documented: It takes one second to post to SES. But my SES account allows 14 of these per second. 2) How? 3)No can do - too expensive.

Comment: 1) Therefore its not SES, its on your side 2) no idea 3) fair enough. Conclusion = you can't do much. One idea just popped in my head, you could try concurrent connections to SES. Try doing 2 simultaneous requests to your PHP script. Of course, with different email lists.

Comment: I doubt its your code. Its your hardware/network connectivity. You could try adding more mail address in $MAIL and see if SES accepts them.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this yet, but I'm going to split the array of emails into 5 chunks, and pass each one simultaneously through the HTTP-POST routine. In principle, that should cut the send-rate by 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

With my previous experience I found reusing your cURL handle reduces overhead significantly. Simply only do curl_init() once and only set the options that change each time.

The other thing you could do is use mutli curl which allows curl to handle making it multithreaded.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: Also, as was confirmed in the thread you posted on at amazon, SES does indeed allow for keep-alive so enabling that will further increase your throughput if you reuse your curl handle.

Comment: `$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";`
`$headers[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";`

Comment: cURL's multi interface is not multithreaded.  It uses non-blocking calls so that you can send multiple requests in parallel.  Additionally, you do not need to reuse easy handles when using cURL's multi interface because a multi handle maintains its own internal connection cache.  http://curl.haxx.se/dev/internals.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [batches](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=CFRuntime/batch). Configure 14 emails at once, and collect each CURL hangle by returning it, instead of immediate processing - see [returnCurlHandle](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonSES/send_email) option.

Thus there will be 14 concurrent CURL sessions, and all batch will take about 2-4 seconds to process.